# Clean way to do nested lazy evaluation in rlang

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, tidyverse

Let's say I have a function `f` that takes a bunch of arguments, along with an optional extra argument.

```
f <- function(..., extra)
{
    arglst <- lapply(quos(...), get_expr)
    if(!missing(extra))
    {
        extra <- get_expr(enquo(extra))
        arglst <- c(arglst, extra=extra)
    }
    arglst
    ## ... do something with argument list ... ##
}

f(a, extra=foo)
# [[1]]
# a
# 
# $extra
# foo
```

Note that I don't want to evaluate the arguments as such, but I do want to get the expressions that were passed in, to be evaluated by other code down the line.

The new [rlang](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/index.html) package (which powers the next version of dplyr, to be released on CRAN Real Soon Now) provides extensive facilities for lazy evaluation which I'm using in `f` above. For example `quos`, `get_expr` and `enquo` are all functions from rlang.

In `f`, the part where I process `extra` is actually boilerplate code: I'll want to do this in other functions, not just in `f`. I don't want to rewrite it each time, so I thought I'd put it into its own function:

```
doExtra <- function(arglst, extra)
{
    if(!missing(extra))
    {
        extra <- get_expr(enquo(extra))
        arglst <- c(arglst, extra=extra)
    }
    arglst
}

f2 <- function(..., extra)
{
    arglst <- lapply(quos(...), get_expr)
    arglst <- doExtra(arglst, extra)
    arglst
}
```

The problem is that when I do it this way, the value of `extra` that `doExtra` sees is what's passed in from `f2`, not the original:

```
f2(a, extra=foo)
# [[1]]
# a
#
# $extra
# extra
```

How can I modify `f` to isolate the boilerplate code, without getting the wrong result? I can do something like manipulate the environment of `doExtra`'s calling frame directly, but that would be exceedingly ugly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- To forward a named argument to another enquoting function, you have to enquote then unquote: `!! enquo(arg)`. If you just pass `enquo(arg)`, the enquoting function will see just that: `enquo(arg)`. If you pass the argument symbol, that's what it will see as well. That's why you need to unquote within the argument it captures.

  `!! enquo(arg)` triggers the evaluation of `enquo(arg)`, which returns the expression supplied to the `arg` argument. Then it is unquoted inside the argument captured by your function.
- If you are enquoting a potentially missing argument, it's better to enquote it and then check for missingness with `quo_is_missing()`. Enquoting a missing argument creates the same object returned by calling `quo()` without argument.
- If you don't need quosures, you can use `exprs()` and `enexpr()`. However you're losing the environment and you are making further evaluation brittle.

  If you are capturing the environment in some other way to evaluate it with `base::eval()` or similar, please note that quosures can contain other quosures. Only `eval_tidy()` will understand these nested quosures.

IIUC your question, it's about passing an argument that should be enquoted to another function. One way to do it is to capture in the first function, then pass by value to the second function:

```
library("purrr")
library("rlang")

f <- function(..., extra) {
  exprs <- exprs(...)

  # Pass the enquoted argument by value
  exprs <- extra_by_value(exprs, enexpr(extra))

  exprs
}
extra_by_value <- function(exprs, extra) {
  if (!is_missing(extra)) {
    c(exprs, extra = extra)
  } else {
    exprs
  }
}
```

If the second function has to take by expression rather than by value (perhaps because it is another user-facing verb), you have to unquote the enquoted expression:

```
f <- function(..., extra) {
  exprs <- exprs(...)

  # Since the argument is captured by the function, we need
  # to unquote the relevant expression into the argument:
  exprs <- extra_by_expression(exprs, !! enexpr(extra))

  exprs
}
extra_by_expression <- function(exprs, extra) {
  extra <- enexpr(extra)
  if (!is_missing(extra)) {
    c(exprs, extra = extra)
  } else {
    exprs
  }
}
```

All those concepts apply to quosures. Here is the equivalent code:

```
f <- function(..., extra) {
  quos <- quos(...)

  # Since the argument is captured by the function, we need
  # to unquote the relevant expression into the argument:
  quos <- extra_by_expression(quos, !! enquo(extra))

  quos
}
extra_by_expression <- function(quos, extra) {
  extra <- enquo(extra)
  if (!quo_is_missing(extra)) {
    c(quos, extra = extra)
  } else {
    quos
  }
}
```

It is almost always better to use quosures than raw expressions because they keep track of their context.

Comment: Using quosures is problematic because the downstream code does NSE of its own. The extra_by_expression code doesn't work for me (it seems to be parsing `!!` as `!( !(...))`) but the extra_by_value works. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say it's not using quosures that is problematic, it's doing NSE in a non-tidy way ;)

Comment: I tried something similar: `outer(columnName)` calling `inner(columnName)` calling dplyr functions using `columnName`. Both `outer` and `inner` use `enquo` and then `!!`. `inner` alone works, but `outer` does not. What do you mean by using NSE in a non-tidy way?

Comment: It should work. Could you post a question with a reprex please? By non-tidy NSE, I mean NSE without quosures and without quasiquotation.